# How can I use keytool or openssl to generate a signed certificate?

Tags: java, openssl, keytool, jks

How can I use keytool or openssl to generate a signed certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out foo.pem -keyout foo.key
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a self signed certificates openssl can be used and these certificates can be added in a truststore using keytool so that client can determine whether a certificate is trusted on not using truststore (keystore) file.

Please find below a step by step guide to create a self signed certificate following :-

http://blogs.techcushions.com/2016/12/creating-self-signed-certificates.html

Best Regards.